# Render plain SVG without shadow quickly

Tags: rendering, light, svg

What is the best way to render a 2d animated video which is made of imported SVG files from Inkscape? I already set the Environment Lighting (to 1.250) and set the Gather to Approximate. This only gives nice results with an error lower than 0.200, otherwise there are artefacts like gray circles. I am using the Blender Render (should I use Cycles Render?) and would like to have a FullHD Output (1920 x 1080) with 24fps for my 5 min long video. Currently it takes almost a minute per frame (I have a Core i5 6600).
I hope there is a way to improve my render settings...
Thanks.

(Look I want to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSKi8HfcxEk)

Comment: Not answering the question, but the video is pretty interesting.

Comment: You could probably switch to Blender Internal render engine and use the viewport OpenGL render engine alone, That is probably the fastest most flexible way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shadeless material option in the Properties panel for each material,and that will keep you from having to use things like AO or anything like that. You can mimic the shadeless material in Cycles with an emission shader on everything, but I think the rendering in Blender Render for this type is faster.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used this https://code.blender.org/2011/05/scripting-–-change-settings-the-fast-way/ script to set all materials to shadeless at once and now it renders with Raytrace in just one second per frame! Awesome!